# This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with a method that returns result, when i step through debugging i get DenyAnyGet on JsonRequestBehavior. Any idea what could be an issue? I need some assistance please mates. The GetData method uses SortByColumnWithOrder below and maybe i am missing something and fix my table as well to allow data to filter not null. As i thought before it was the reason, but getting DenyGet i am bit confused now.

```
public ActionResult GetData()
            {
                //Server side Parameter.
                JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

                try
                {
                    // Initilization
                  string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
                   // string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
                    string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
                    string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
                    int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
                    int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);


                    // Loading.
                    List<EventsManagementTb> data = this.LoadData();

                    // Total record count.

                    int totalRecords = data.Count;

                    // Verification.
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
                    {
                        // Apply search

                        data = data.Where(l=>l.TrainingType.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.TrainingDescription.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.Price.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.Venue.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.Facilitator.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.WhoAttend.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.RSVP.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
                    }

                    // Sorting
                    data = this.SortByColumnWithOrder(order, orderDir, data);

                    // Filter record data.
                    int recFilter = data.Count;

                    // Apply pagination.

                    data = data.Skip(startRec).Take(pageSize).ToList();

                    result = this.Json(new { draw = Request["draw"], recordsTotal = totalRecords, recordsFiltered = recFilter, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                return result;// This gets hits here.

            }

    private List<EventsManagementTb> SortByColumnWithOrder(string order, string orderDir, List<EventsManagementTb> data)
        {
            // Initialization.
            List<EventsManagementTb> lst = new List<EventsManagementTb>();

            try
            {
                // Sorting
                switch (order)
                {
                    case "0":

                        lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.TrainingType).ToList()
                                            : data.OrderBy(l => l.TrainingType).ToList();
                        break;

                    case "1":
                        lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.TrainingDescription).ToList()
                                    : data.OrderBy(l => l.TrainingDescription).ToList();
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.Price).ToList()
                            : data.OrderBy(l => l.Price).ToList();
                        break;

                    case "3":
                        lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.Venue).ToList()
                            : data.OrderBy(l => l.Venue).ToList();
                        break;


                    case "4":

                        lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.Facilitator).ToList()
                            : data.OrderBy(l => l.Facilitator).ToList();
                        break;

                    case "5":

                        lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.WhoAttend).ToList()
                            : data.OrderBy(l => l.WhoAttend).ToList();
                        break;

                    default:

                        lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.RSVP).ToList()
                            : data.OrderBy(l => l.RSVP).ToList();
                        break;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }


            return lst;
        }

 private List<EventsManagementTb> LoadData()
        {
            List<EventsManagementTb> lst = new List<EventsManagementTb>();

            try
            {
                string line = string.Empty;
                string srcFilePath = "content/files/EventsManagementTb.txt";
                var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, srcFilePath);
                string filePath = new Uri(fullPath).LocalPath;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

                //Read file

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    EventsManagementTb tb = new EventsManagementTb();
                    string[] info = line.Split(',');

                    // Setting

                    tb.TrainingType = info[0].ToString();
                    tb.TrainingDescription = info[1].ToString();
                    tb.Price = Convert.ToInt32(info[2].ToString());
                    tb.Venue = info[3].ToString();
                    tb.Facilitator = info[4].ToString();
                    tb.WhoAttend = info[5].ToString();
                    tb.RSVP = info[6].ToString();

                    // Adding
                    lst.Add(tb);
                }
                sr.Dispose();
                sr.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            return lst;
        }

    }
```